# Get outside id from inner click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

How can you get "id_edge" after clicking the button?

```
<div id="id_edge">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button id="button">click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need to?  What problem are you trying to solve?  I suspect there's a cleaner way to solve it than what you're suggesting.

Comment: Do you need to get the element that has the id of 'id_edge'. Or do you need to get the id itself?

Answer (score 1):

I answered it myself:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
var result = btn.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
```

will give the `id` `id_edge`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(){

var whatYouWant = $(this).parent().eq(4).attr(id);

});
```

Will give you the `id` `id_edge`

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery :

```
$('#button').on('click', function(ev) {
  // closest() will search in all parents,
  // not only the first level like parent().
  var id_edge = $(ev.target).closest('[id]');
});
```